# Element componentValidation is not defided in variable

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-11

There's a method in one of my components `componentValitation.cfc`:

```
<cffunction name="getValidationTypeRegExpByID" access="public" 
      returntype="string" output="false">

    <cfargument name="componentValidationTypeID" type="numeric" required="true">
    <cfscript>
        if (structKeyExists(variables.componentValidationTypes, arguments.componentValidationTypeID))
        {
            return variables.componentValidationTypes[arguments.componentValidationTypeID].RegExp;
        }
        return '';
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

I want to call the above mentioned method from another component. I tried calling it from `common.cfc` like this

```
var advertisement = getComponentValidation('component','sys.jo.core.fe.componentValidation');
<cfset testttt = advertisement.getValidationTypeRegExpByID(componentValidationTypeID) />
<cfset errorMessage = "#componentShortLabel# #Lib.showCaption('message_Decimal2dpValidation', UserIdentity)#" />
<cfset arguments.Message.addValidationError( keyName=QuestionID,  errorMessage=errorMessage, componentKey=ComponentID, componentErrorMessage=errorMessage, tupleIndex=arguments.tupleIndex, QuestionDisplayNumber=errorDisplaySequenceNumber ) />
```

But I'm getting an error like Elementcomponent is not defined in variable in `componentValidation.cfc` (which was already defined in my `init()` function). Any ideas?

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  If you have a variable named `componentValidation.cfc`, dump it and see what's in it.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk there is variablevalidationtypes add it giving correct validation type

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a mistake:

```
var advertisement = getComponentValidation('component','sys.jo.core.fe.componentValidation');
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
var advertisement = createobject('component','sys.jo.core.fe.componentValidation');
```